# Angular 14 - Compiling and symbolik link

Tags: angular

I need to put a symbolic link in my assets when deploying.

Take this path for example:

```
<img src="ui/assets/static/logo_customer.png" />
```

The image is currently a static file inside src/assets/static that build copy into dist directory.

I need to allow sys admin to change logo based on customer on the deploy server.

So I've create a directory in /var/lib/software/frontend_static where put every file I may need to customize for specific customer.

I put a symlink inside /src/static that point to /var/lib.... (ln -s etc...)

Unfortunally, when I compile, this link is dropped and disapper in dist/assets/static directory.

I've tryed with preserverSymLink in angular.json, tsconfig and as parameter in ng build but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to preserve a sym link?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to have the angular.json flag set to true AND the build flag ng build --preserve-symlinks at the same time?